# NSWindow close button is disabled

Tags: cocoa

[image]Goal: window close button to be present at all times..

I tried to use

```
   override func viewDidAppear() {           
    var button = view.window?.standardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.CloseButton)
    button?.enabled = true
     }
```

But when i move from one view controller to the other, the  close window button is still disabled. Note that the view controllers are presented as sheets..

How can i have the button enabled in all view controllers?

Comment: Do you mean disabling close button when a sheet view is appearing?

Comment: Yes thats what happens, BUT i want the close button to be visible at all sheet views

Comment: Is your sample code from sheet controller or from main controller?

Comment: i put it in both...

Comment: I'm trying to repeat your situation with code in sheet controller. It's look like it doesn't work. At first row standardWindowButton returns nil so second row doesn't work at all. Could you check `button` variable is not empty?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of the setup. How do i check if its empty?

Comment: At the above setup as you can see it goes from ViewController to view2 and vice versa via segues. Once the App launches close button is there, once the first transition to a different VC is made it disappears for good. My goal is the button to be there forever..

Comment: Something like that `print("close button is \(button)")`

Comment: In the sheet controller `view.window?` is not a window of the app. It's window created on fly only for a sheet and this window doesn't have title and standard buttons. But when i tried this code with really main window it doesn't work too. I think your are digging in wrong way.

Comment: https://filetea.me/t1spRvV3lHDRnOQxxcDvw2frg    i have uploaded my example, delete everything that i did so far as it clearly doesnt give me re desired result.. could you please have a look at it??